# Is there any way by which i can download my Google Compute Engine Virtual Machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am running a project on Google compute engine. I want to create a same duplicate version of my virtual machine on other domain. Is there any way by which i can download my Google Compute Engine VM and upload it to any other VM.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new **disk** in Project 2 by a **snapshot/image** in Project 1. There are several method to do this, you can find in [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries). I just suggest two.

**REST API method**

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{Project2}/zones/{zone}/disks

with
Resquest-body

```
{
  "name": "my-new-disk-in-project2",
  "sourceSnapshot": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{Project1}/global/snapshots/{snapshot-name}"
}
```

**Python Client API method**

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
import google.cloud
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
body = {
  "name": "my-new-disk-in-project2",
  "sourceSnapshot": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{Project1}/global/snapshots/{snapshot-name}"
}

request = service.disks().insert(project={Project2}, zone=zone, body=body)
response = request.execute()
```

**Finally**

Create your instance by disk, there is still many method to do this, simplest way is click the button in console (Compute Engine -> Disks -> your-new-disk -> Create Instance).

Comment: @ZulkiflAgha, May I know if this solve your problem, or you still want some way to download the file (as I know you can't).